# How to insert a file with a list into a script?

Tags: python, list, file, join, bitcoin

I am trying to add a list file to a script.
I need to make it so that to take the public key data from the `"list.txt"` file and save all the results to the `"save.txt"` file?

```
from bitcoinlib.keys import Address

master = Address ("0341b40ab5b2972161f2ff3d5487e0fb8260f2d98221cc2eb4fa3f28b6ad10d81e", encoding = 'bech32', script_type = 'p2wpkh')
print (master.address)
```

At the moment I am getting one value

```
bc1q7wdz5dcs553f2y6qgf38xdgqs2kqgkhn5ydn9l
```

How to fix that in place of this value: `0341b40ab5b2972161f2ff3d5487e0fb8260f2d98221cc2eb4fa3f28b6ad10d81e`

There was a list of this file `"list.txt"`

```
02485a4e62913be3db116d1ab15f84110599ea8905cd7dbae7be6fa02033fdb54e
0315da5f8f47787f6e8294bd369a4dd81aea97429630ecae831a9f6362a6917106
023741e71ebddc5eca046c9b23ac7c5230160fe1335e655c9bbe0b8a20c8d89802
037782a3fcc6c0ca092658a513c9f051cc95d540d215f0c965176c664d49d3e732
029c6c7748107fc9584a838df6a2c8224ae2339e2a95b15b4cd8bcc67c2d149cd5
```

To get all the value and save to the file "save.txt"

```
bc1q6jxrahx3rw6lt2nlv5fpsdtllyzaa03m4d98xv
bc1qct3fu8543tryapkq4kpgw5ph8cj74zhtrdp5sx
bc1q5a3h25vu4kn90sc70rkm65narezzw97khu4dhu
bc1qutzkrtc7tqqjgrzns3s3h92f8wfxvfhp99ppnn
bc1ql2slqxzp7c9hdxhlp0ehlzdg2qa94xh5lk2anw
```

Please help me with fixing the code!

Comment: I have no idea what you're expecting `script_type` to mean, and I have no idea what the `'bech32'` encoding or `'p2wpkh'` script type are supposed to be. Also, a newline is represented as `\n`, *without* a space in between. Anyway, it's not clear what the actual problem is. What happens when you try the code as is, and how is it different from what is supposed to happen? What problem do you want to solve by "inserting" the part you find confusing? And when you read the relevant documentation, how exactly did it not answer your questions?

Comment: with open ("list.txt") as myfile:
    data = "\n" .join (line.rstrip () for line in myfile)


    with open ("save.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write (str (data))
        file.write ("\n")

Try this and show us the error

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I want to make a script to handle multiple public keys instead of one. I just have a large list of public keys in the file. How do I fix the top first code? Need to insert the file "list.txt"

Comment: Where you say "approximately it works as shown in this code", **what does that mean**? What is "approximate" about it? What is different between the result you get, and the result you need? I don't understand what this `Address` class is for (especially since I can't *see it*, nor its documentation) and I don't understand what **task you accomplish** by creating an Address object and then getting its `.address`.

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `python process all lines of a file` into a search engine?

Comment: @ Karl Knechtel Sorry for my broken english. I provided the second script as an example that I tried to combine the first script with the second. All this I did not succeed :( Due to not knowing the programming.

Comment: @Bashen: Can you give an example, how `save.txt` should look like (please edit your question) ?

Comment: @Maurice Meyer I have corrected the question. I need that in the place where the value 0341b40ab5b2972161f2ff3d5487e0fb8260f2d98221cc2eb4fa3f28b6ad10d81e is located insert the file "list.txt". How to make the script process several values in one run?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i'm concerned you want to use each line of file separately.
First read all the lines to list:

```py
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
   lists = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in f.readlines()]
```

Then for each line, create `Address` instance, and save it to another list:

```py
addresses = []
for l in lists:
    master = Address(l, encoding = 'bech32', script_type = 'p2wpkh')
    addresses.append(master.address)
```

The last part is to save all to file `save.txt`

```py
with open('save.txt', 'w+') as f:
   for a in addresses:
      f.write(a + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you ! More health to you!